# Woocommerce Product Gallery Lightbox Problem

Tags: woocommerce, lightbox, image-gallery, prettyphoto, woocommerce-theming

I am using Woocommerce Product Gallery and encounter some problem.

I would like to change how the lightbox is displayed in "Product Gallery".

As I need to users to click on the hyperlink in the Media Description,

1. Replaced the "Caption" with Photo "Title"
2. Replace the Photo "Title" underneath the photo with Media "description"(Hopefully HTML enabled, so that the users can directly click in the link inside "Description"

Example screenshot:

[image]

This problem really bothers me a lot...

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your custom CSS stylesheet or input box in the theme settings then itshould do the trick.

```
body.single-product .ppt, body.single-product .pp_description {
display: none !important;
}
```

I tested this on one of my sites just now with WooCommerce and it worked sweet.